# Strange Redis SET command behaviour

Tags: redis

I'm writing a simple program for testing Redis:

```
#include <hiredis.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    redisContext * c = redisConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);

    redisReply * reply;

    reply = redisCommand(c, "FLUSHALL");
    freeReplyObject(reply);

    for(long int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {   
        char query[64];
        sprintf(query, "SET %ld \"string%ld\"", i, i); 

        reply = redisCommand(c, query);
        freeReplyObject(reply);

        if( !(i % 100000) )
        {   
            reply = redisCommand(c, "DBSIZE");
            int res = reply->integer;
            freeReplyObject(reply);

            printf("%s\n", query);
            printf("dbsize: %d\n", res);
        }   
    }   

    redisFree(c);
}
```

It should put 1000000 keys into db, but the output is the following:

```
SET 0 "string0"
dbsize: 1
SET 100000 "string100000"
dbsize: 100001
SET 200000 "string200000"
dbsize: 200001
SET 300000 "string300000"
dbsize: 300001
SET 400000 "string400000"
dbsize: 400001
SET 500000 "string500000"
dbsize: 500001
SET 600000 "string600000"
dbsize: 600001
SET 700000 "string700000"
dbsize: 700001
SET 800000 "string800000"
dbsize: 779479
SET 900000 "string900000"
dbsize: 779479
SET 1000000 "string1000000"
dbsize: 779479
```

So in one moment (usually about after 600000 key) Redis stops adding records. What can be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not check errors in your code, so it is difficult to diagnose the issue. You are suppose to analyse the output before freeing the reply object.

The most probable reason is your Redis instance has been configured with a maxmemory limit, and you have reached this limit. You may want to check the configuration file, or use the following command:

```
config get maxmemory
```

A zero value means there is no limit. Otherwise, the limit is epxressed in number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped.

Error checking was unusefull - there were no errors.